# Office365 Management API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-restapi

I was trying to access Office365 Audit logs through Office365 Management API([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn707383.aspx)). I have done most of the configurations as described in the link. I am able to get AuzreActiveDirectory audit data. But SharePoint and Exchange audit logs are not working.

Note: I have not used webhook. Does this has something to do?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webhooks are optional.  Once you subscribe to a particular content type (EXO, SPO, AAD), you can periodically poll for new content using the /content operation.

When you first subscribe, there can be a lag before data is first available.  Are you still not seeing EXO or SPO data?

Comment: Yes, now I am able to see. Initially there was lag for more than 12 hours